# How can I upload mp4 files to phone from mac?

Tags: phone-connector-mac

I have just installed the Windows Phone app on my mac, and I want to copy some mp4 files to the phone. How can I do that? Is there any way to see the phone as a drive?

Comment: The Windows Phone app for Mac has the ability to sync music from iTunes, have you tried that?

Comment: yes, but it does not show mp4 files in my iTunes, also I can't sync individual files

Comment: You pick the songs or playlists, not individual files. Also, only songs that are compatible (ie. not DRM protected) will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a windows phone, I will assume that you have a one drive account.  So upload your file from Mac to one drive, then download the file from one drive to your phone trough the one drive app.

Answer (score 0):

In order to transfer files from Windows Phone to MAC, you need to download an app called FEEM.
Go through the following article
http://www.techanges.com/share-files-between-windows-phone-and-iphone/

I too had this problem. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Click this [link](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-CA/How-to/wp8/windows-phone-app-for-mac) for windows phone App for mac and install it and read instructions.

Very good for [synchronization](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-CA/how-to/wp8/music-and-videos/sync-with-my-mac) of photos and iTunes.

**Simply you can drag and drop mp4 files on this left side menu of this app**

Answer (score 0):

Install "FTP Server" app from Windows Store, open it, select the "Downloads" folder and connect to your smartphone with a ftp client.